# Entity Framework References, Multi Layer App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have set up my MVC app with seperate Class Libraries for my Domain (POCOs) and Repositories. Now my DbConxet is currently in the domain layer and i wanted to add the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

but it couldnt find DbModelBuilder. Now I checked my references and noticed it was referencing EFCodeFirst0.8/lib/EntityFramework.dll When I changed this to EntityFramework4.2.0.0/lib/EntityFramework.dll DbModelBuilder was available but I get errors because the other projects in my solution (MVC and Repo) are referencing the original dll. So I update them but then the MVC layer has a problem in App_Start/SQLCEEntityFramework.cs

What have I done wrong?! Should I have the OnModelCreating in another part of my app and reset all the references to the original EFCodeFirst0.8/lib/EntityFramework.dll? Or fix up the errors in App_Start/SQLCEEntityFramework.cs?

Thanks all,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You are doing it wrong :)*

There is really no point in POCO, repository pattern, and all that stuff intended for **persistance ignorance**, when you have entity framework referenced everywhere and your domain is tied with it.

Your domain should be pure class library (with things like componentmodel, dataannotations of course) without referencing EF.

Then you should have "contract" (that is interface, in another class library) between your MVC app and "all the possible repositories" - also EF agnostic.

And finally you have "one particular implementation" of that contract - your EF repository. That should be the only project referencing EF library.

The point is, that if tommorow your boss comes and says "ok, we switching to nhibernate", you sould replay "no problem, i just write another repository implementing this interface with it and change 1 line in IoC container configuration". And as a bonus, you can update your EF reference in 1 place only :)

Comment: Ok so would it be better if I have a Project.IRepository class library which the Service layer talks to/knows about and then a Project.EFRepository with implementations of Project.IRepository classes which contains reference to EF and had dbContext? Can I remove the reference to EF in my MVC layer?

Comment: Thanks rouen, think its starting to make a lot of sense now!

Comment: You should judge the amount of labor required to code to persistence ignorance vs the odds you'd ever have to change (plus changing is never as simple as you imagine it would be). If your web layer is ignorant of the underlying DB you'll likely end up with many painful performance issues down the road. Plus debugging through many dependencies is no fun. In my experience it's never paid off to have repository abstractions. Just treat the EF context as your repository and use it in your services/controllers as needed.

Comment: Of course it depends on the size of project.. in small project, I agree with your approach, but my answer was based on facts provided - already using repository pattern, persistance ignorant domain objects etc, so I suppose he has reason for them and I just corrected his errors in using them.